# Capistrano will not create releases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

When I run `cap deploy`, Capistrano will attempt to create a folder such as `$HOME/sites/MY_APP/releases/TIMESTAMP`. I can see the command attempting to run, but it will not actually create the folder.

I can copy the command directly out of the Capistrano output and run the command over SSH and it works great with no problems.

The command looks something so:

```
cp -RPp /home/some_user/sites/my_cool_app/shared/cached-copy /home/some_user/sites/my_cool_app/releases/20111123164239 && (echo 59bf115868c2430cd0475ca1596998f1cfa3c084 > /home/some_user/sites/my_cool_app/releases/20111123164239/REVISION)
```

Why would the command fail through Capistrano, but succeed through an SSH terminal?

Comment: Capistrano rolls back if something else fails. Can you post the capistrano output, and while you're on it, the output of cap deploy:check ?

Comment: Cap returns `You appear to have all necessary dependencies installed` from cap `deploy:check`

Comment: A number of things could be off: Is the folder writeable by the user you are using to login to the server? Is something else failing in the deployment script?

Comment: I haven't figured this one out yet but the issue appears to be coming from the fact the `$HOME/sites/MY_APP/releases` directory doesn't exist. If you ssh in and create the releases directory manually it temporarily solves the problem. Still trying to figure out why cap isn't doing this like it has done before.

Comment: Steve: The releases directory should be created by `deploy:setup`, which you [should run before the first deploy](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/e092693/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb#L174).

Comment: deploy:setup was removed from capistrano3 https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/1788#issuecomment-253565420

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm still not sure where the problem spans from but removing the line:

```
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
```

Solved things for me. It looks like a bug where the releases directory isn't being created and so removing that line skips that step. A better approach if you want to keep the remote_cache is probably to add another step to setup like so:

```
after "deploy:setup", "deploy:create_release_dir"
namespace :deploy do
  task :create_release_dir, :except => {:no_release => true} do
    run "mkdir -p #{fetch :releases_path}"
  end
end
```

Comment: 'set :deploy_via, :remote_cache' did not help .. i just created a dir ' run "mkdir -p #{fetch :releases_path}"' like this.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore part below the green lineline, but I will keep them, just for reference for others.

The mentioned issue was happening for me when I was using Capistrano `3.9.x` version. When I downgraded to version `3.4.0` it was all working.

---

Second part of the answer:

Once this happened to me was when the github keys were not set up in `~/.ssh/`.

You should generate a ssh key on the server. Once the `.pub` file is generated in `~/.ssh` then you should go to github.com (or any other service) and add you newly generated ssh key on the web-site (it should be found under settings page or similar).
Also, on the server add a proper record in `~/.ssh/config` file which matches the identification in the capistrano deploy script:

```
set :repo_url, proc { "git@github.com:your_git_name/#{fetch(:application)}.git" }
```

So the `config` file should look like this:

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
    User git
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_my_new_key_on_the_server
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a matter of adding this line into deploy.rb file

```
set :scm, :git
```